# SELECT INTO using union of two old tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I am trying to issue a `SELECT * INTO <new_table_name> FROM <old_table_name>` statement where my select statement is the result of combining two other tables.

In pseudocode format, it would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table1>
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM <table2>

INTO 
<new_table>
```

None of my current attempts have been valid. Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INTO` will go immediate after `SELECT` statement (`SELECT . . .  INTO`) :

```
SELECT *
INTO <new_table>
FROM <table1> 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM <table2>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Comment: slight typo @JerryM. that's all. :)

Comment: @scsimon. . . Thanks.

Comment: The edit was gracious and worked successfully. I am new to DBA type work so I appreciate the help very much so.

Comment: Working examples (and one not working, from prior to the edit): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31ae5e1bb001fc83ab98ac62b20a6a8f

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into SQL Joins?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

I tend to find joins pretty easy to use when I want to combine two tables. I hope this helps!

Comment: `JOIN` will not help.